# Finding perpendicular projection of the vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

In the space $\mathbb{R}^3$ find perpendicular projection  of the vector $\alpha =(1,1,1)$ on the space $V= \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x_1+2x_2-x_3=0 \}$ and find perpendicular projection of $\alpha$ on a line $L=((1,2,3))$. How to do this because i have utterly no idea even how to start?

Comment: What do you know about perpendicular projection (aka orthogonal projection)? That's usually a good starting point for a question about a topic, and putting that information in the question would help avoid it being closed for "missing context or other details".

Comment: I know that this projection is an endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that any vector from this set can be represented as a sum of vector one from a subspace V and the other from the ortoghonal V.

Comment: I have no idea why you want this topic to be closed.

Comment: It's not so much a question of wanting to close, as wanting better information about the question. As it stands, one can write a long answer as I just did without knowing how much of it is simply repeating stuff you already know, and how badly it misses the points that are actually confusing you.

Comment: do you know how to orthogonally  project a vector onto another vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know that a vector $v$ can be expressed as the sum
$v = v_\parallel + v_\perp$
where $v_\parallel$ is in the subspace $V$ and $v_\perp$ is orthogonal to $V$.
The vector $v_\parallel$ is what we generally mean by the orthogonal
or perpendicular projection of $v$ onto $V$.

In general, if $v \in \mathbb R^n$
and $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$,
then $v$ is the sum of $n$ orthogonal vectors of the form
$(v\cdot e_i)\, e_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.
Given an $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$,
if you can choose $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ so that $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$
is an orthonormal basis of $V$, then 
$\{e_{m+1},\ldots,e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of the orthogonal complement of $V$,
and you then have the necessary tools to represent both $v_\parallel$ and $v_\perp$
as sums of vectors of the form $(v\cdot e_i)\, e_i$.

For $n=3$ the task is simplified, since there are only four possibilities:
$V=\mathbb R^3$, $V=\{0\}$, $V$ is one-dimensional, 
or the orthogonal complement of $V$ is one-dimensional.
Orthogonal projections in the first two cases are trivial, and in the other
two cases, either $v_\parallel$ or $v_\perp$ are easily found if you can identify
one unit vector in the relevant one-dimensional subspace.
And of course once you find one of $v_\parallel$ or $v_\perp$ you can use 
$v = v_\parallel + v_\perp$ to find the other.

In the particular case  $V= \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x_1+2x_2-x_3=0 \}$,
you may notice that $x_1+2x_2-x_3=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\cdot(1,2,-1)$,
from which we can deduce the identity of one vector orthogonal to $V$.

Now if you consider how you can find $(v\cdot e_i)\, e_i$ when you have
$v$ and a vector $u = ce_i$, for some scalar constant $c$,
you can derive the general formulas for finding the orthogonal projection of
$v$ onto a planar subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ given any vector orthogonal to the plane,
and the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^3$
given any vector in that subspace.