# Locus of points r such that r.n=d where d is a constant

Tags: vectors

## The Question

Let **n** be a unit vector, and let *d* be a constant. What is the locus of points **r** such that $\mathbf{r}.\mathbf{n}=$*d* ?

## The Attempt

So I know that $\mathbf{a}.\mathbf{b}=\left|a\right|\left|b\right|\cos(\text{angle between a and b})$, but I am not sure how to use this to find what I need.

## Edit 1

Using the dot product,
$$d=\mathbf{r}.\mathbf{n}=\left|\mathbf{r}\right|\left|\mathbf{n}\right|\cos\theta\text{  where }\left|\mathbf{n}\right|=1$$
$$d=\left|\mathbf{r}\right|\cos\theta$$
Using the orthogonal projection,
$$\mathbf{r}=d\mathbf{n}+d\tan\theta \mathbf{n'}\text{  where }\mathbf{n'}\text{ is orthogonal to }\mathbf{n}$$

Comment: Hint: $\;\mathbf{r} = d \, \mathbf{n} + \mathbf{r'}$ where $\mathbf{r'} \perp \mathbf{n}\;$.

Comment: Sorry @dxiv how did you get this result? Also how do I find what the length of **r'** is?

Comment: That's the orthogonal decomposition of vector $\mathbf r$ in a component alongside $\mathbf n$ and a component orthogonal to $\mathbf n$. See for example [1](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalDecomposition.html), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893502/orthogonal-projection-from-one-vector-onto-another), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179772/finding-perpendicular-projection-of-the-vector). In this case, 
$d \,\mathbf n$ is the projection of $\mathbf r$ onto $\mathbf n$, and $\mathbf{r'} = \mathbf r - d \,\mathbf n$ is the component orthogonal to $\mathbf n$.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv I have updated the post to reflect what I have understood from that. Can I leave **r** in that form?

Comment: Any vector $r=d \,\mathbf{n} + \mathbf{r'}$ with $\mathbf{r'} \perp \mathbf{n}$ satisfies $\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{n} = d$, and the converse is also true. $\mathbf{r'}$ lies in the plane orthogonal to $\mathbf{n}$, so the locus is that plane translated by $d\,\mathbf n$. For a simple example in the 3D cartesian space $r = x \cdot \mathbf i + y \cdot \mathbf j + z \cdot \mathbf k$, the locus of $\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf k = d$ is the plane parallel to $(x, y)$ at height $z = d$.